# compilation step in keras sequential model throwing the error "ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer:

Tags: keras, classification, perceptron

I'm trying to develop as classifier for two classes. I've implemented the model as follows:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential() #using tensorflow's version of keras
model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = X_train_scaled[:,1].shape))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(250,activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50,activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2,activation="softmax"))
model.summary()
```

[image]

```
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer = "sgd",
             metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

The size of the inputs are

```
X_train_scaled[:,1].shape, y_train.shape
((552,), (552,))
```

The entire error message is:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer:
expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 552 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that you defined a model which expects as input a shape of (batch_size, 552) and you are trying to feed it an array with a shape of (batch_size, 1).

The issue is most likely with

```
input_shape = X_train_scaled[:,1].shape)
```

This should most likely be:

```
input_shape = X_train_scaled.shape[1:]
```

i.e. you want to define the shape of your model to the the shape of the features (without the number of examples). The model is then fed in mini-batches... e.g. if you do call `model.fit(X_train_scaled, ...)` keras will create mini-batches (of 32 examples by default) and update the model weights for each mini batch.

Also, please be aware that you defined the model to return a shape of (batch_size, 2). So y_train must have a shape of (X_train.shape[0], 2).

Comment: That was my problem, thanks. My thinking was definitely muddy on this one.

Comment: @JeffreyWhite if you believe it does answer your question, please mark the answer as accepted. It helps other users understand that may be looking at questions know that your question is answered and not waste their time analysing the question.

Comment: Pedro answered my question

Comment: @JeffreyWhite there should be a button next to the answer voting arrows (top left of the answer) that allows you to make the answer as accepted.

Comment: Found it. Thanks for helping a Newby

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered by Pedro